# Angular: Add fields to an enum (like swift/kotlin) best way?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I'm from the mobile world, and I'm learning angular for a project.

I wish I could add fields to an enum like swift or Kotlin, for example in swift:

```
enum Status: Int {
  case connected = 0, disconnected = 1

  var title: String {
      switch self {
        case .connected:
            return "Connected"
        case .disconnected:
            return "Disconnected"
      }
  }

  var color: UIColor {
    switch self {
      case .connected:
        return .green
      case .disconnected:
        return .red
    }
  }

}
```

Using:

```
let status = Status.connected
print(status.title) // Output Connected
print(status.color) // Output green
```

I try to do this in typescript I saw 2 possibilities which are offered to me the Pipe and namespace

**My solution with pipe method**:

```
export enum Status {
  connected = 0, disconnected = 1
}

@Pipe({name: 'color'})
export class StatusColor implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Status): string {
    switch (value) {
      case Status.connected:
        return 'green';
      case Status.disconnected:
        return 'red';
    }
  }

}

@Pipe({name: 'title'})
export class StatusTitle implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Status): string {
    switch (value) {
      case Status.connected:
        return 'Connected';
      case Status.disconnected:
        return 'Disconnected';
    }
  }

}
```

Using in html:

```
user.status | color
user.status | title
```

This solution is for me the most beautiful when I call it in my html code, but the problem is that for each field I have to create a custom pipe and declare it in the app.module. So if I have 3, 4 field it will make me a lot of code, and a lot of declarations in the app.module. Imagine that I have about fifteen enum, .. So is it still a good idea/good practice?

**My solution with namespace method**:

```
export enum Status {
    connected = 0, disconnected = 1
}

export namespace Status {

  export function titleOf(state: Status): string {
    switch (state) {
      case Status.disconnected:
        return 'Disconnected';
      case Status.connected:
        return 'Connected';
    }
  }

  export function colorOf(state: State): string {
    switch (state) {
      case Status.disconnected:
        return 'red';
      case Status.connected:
        return 'green';
    }
  }

}
```

Using from html code:

```
Status.titleOf(user.status)
Status.colorOf(user.status)
```

This second approach is simpler but not as beautiful as the first approach.

So what is the best method to do what I need? Is this a good practice? Can I create a single pipe with sub names for each transformation that could reduce my code?

Comment: Why don't you switch from enum to a static class?

Comment: Because the enum I receive it from the server 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with pipes.

If you don't want to create a custom pipe for each variation, you could simply add an argument to the pipe [as described in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe). I would then create an enum to use as the parameter in order to avoid magic strings floating around:

```
enum StatusType {
  title = 'title',
  color = 'color'
}
```

Then, in the pipe itself, you could add a switch statement based on the StatusType and return the desired value.

Bonus point to use pipe: if the input does not change, the pipe always gives the same result without computation so you gain performances (https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pipes-and-change-detection).